# Multiple jQuery UI Range Sliders Interacting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm creating three separate range sliders with jQuery UI. However, for some reason when moving a handle on a slider the other handle will jump to the position of the corresponding handle on the last slider modified (see gif below). I'd really like to stop this and make the sliders entirely independent.

[image: Broken Sliders]

Currently I've only tested it in Chrome.

[Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/nquinlan/4GLrV/). Below is the relevant code:

#### HTML

```
<ul id="sliders">
    <li id="red">
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="green">
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="blue">
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

#### Javascript

```
$( "#sliders .slider" ).slider({
    range: true,
    orientation: "horizontal",
    min: 0,
    max: 255,
    values: [ 0, 255 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).parent().children(".range").text(ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ]);
    }
});
```

Comment: happens in Firefox also but not every time. Might try using several older versions of jQueryUI to see if it is a bug. Can get them from google CDN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the `.slider()` widget to each item, and not the collection of items.

```
$( "#sliders .slider" ).each(function(){
    $(this).slider({
        range: true,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        min: 0,
        max: 255,
        values: [ 0, 255 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).prev(".range").text(ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ]);
        }
    });
});
```

Also note that you can use `.prev()` instead of `.parent().children()`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! [@SteveStreza had the same answer](https://twitter.com/SteveStreza/status/285124923335262208).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this modification to your code:

```
$("#sliders .slider").each(function() {
    $(this).slider({
        range : true,
        orientation : "horizontal",
        min : 0,
        max : 255,
        values : [0, 255],
        orientation : "horizontal",
        slide : function(event, ui) {
            $(this).parent().children(".range").text(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
}); ​
```

Hope this helps.